# Materialize carousel-item not inheriting default properties

Tags: html, css, reactjs, materialize

Able to fetch the data from API.
But the problem is when I try to map the `carousel-item` inside class `carousel`.
The properties are not being inherited.

When I inspect, I see there are `carousel-item`  inside `carousel`, but they are not having the default properties.

---

This is my Carousel Class

```
class Carousel extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { albums: [] };
}
    componentWillMount() {
      axios.get('http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then(response => this.setState({albums: response.data}));
    }
    renderAlbums(){
      return this.state.albums.map(album =>
            <Card song={album.title} singer={album.artist} src={album.thumbnail_image}/>
      );
     }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carousel center">
        {this.renderAlbums()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Carousel;
```

---

This is my Card Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../App.css';

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="carousel-item center">
        <div className="card z-depth-4">
          <div>
            <img src={this.props.src} className="responsive-img"/>
          </div>
          <p>{this.props.song}</p>

          <div className="singer">{this.props.singer}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Card;
```

---

Please suggest if there is any other way, to import it.
Already have initialised carousel and it's working if I try the [Materialize Example](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try performing your API call in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.

The latter is called *before* the initial render, and thus, if your API call returns before the component finishes mounting, the `setState` statement will not cause a re-render.

With the former, setting the state will always cause a re-render to occur. React documentation recommends initiating data requests from remote endpoints from `componentDidMount`. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: It's not changing, when I add `carousel-item` to the Card. Everything disappears as it get's property of `display:none`, i don't know how.

Comment: And of course, that's a really nice suggestion and explanation. `componentDidMount`

Comment: Oh, so you mean the data is there, it's a CSS issue?

Comment: A potential issue is that the Carousel material component is javascript-based. You might want to have a look at Material-UI (https://material-ui-next.com/) and material-auto-rotating-carousel (https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-auto-rotating-carousel) for React implementations of Materialize components.

Comment: Yeah, it's the CSS issue.

Comment: This thing is strange that, I was able to make it work. But that was quite random. Sometimes it works perfect.And sometimes I add some class, then undo and get back to the previous working state. And it stops working again.